# nginx config for Angular.js Single Page Application

Tags: angularjs, nginx, query-string

I'm trying to host my Angular.js SPA behind nginx but URL's with query params return 403, but URL's without query params just work fine.

Here is my nginx config

```
#||||||||||||||||||||||
# Server for app.test.com
#||||||||||||||||||||||
server {
    listen       8000;
    server_name  app.test.com beta.test.com;
    error_log  logs/app_error.log info;
    access_log  logs/app_acces.log combined;
    root /home/apps/nginx/app;

    location / {
       charset UTF-8;
       try_files  $uri$args $uri$args/ $uri/ /index.html =404; 
    }

     error_page 404 /index.html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firewall was blocking the query params flowing in, had nothing to do with nginx.